# Is it possible to run Desktop application in CICD?

Tags: azure-devops

I am automating functional test cases of a application where major part of it is Web UI but at some steps I have a **desktop application in Main Frames** ,which I automated using **TestStack.White**. I am able to run these test case in Visual Studio on my computer.

We have planned to put these automated test cases in CICD pipeline in VSTS.
Will I able to run test step where desktop application is involve in CICD pipeline?If yes do how can I do it?
Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You can run UI test through [Visual Studio Test task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/vstest?view=azure-devops) (check Test mix contains UI tests option).

Microsoft Hosted agents are pre-configured for UI test for both web apps and desktop apps.

For Self-hosted agent, you need to run it as an interactive process with auto-logon enabled (When configuring agents, select 'No' when prompted to run as a service)

More information: [UI testing considerations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/ui-testing-considerations?tabs=mstest&view=azure-devops)

Comment: Thank you..will go through this articles.